# Hive ORC Writer doesn't support PrimitiveCategory#VOID

Tags: hive

I am trying to store Avro object in ORC format.

The org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroLazyObjectInspector recognise Avro null type as *VOID* primitive which not supported by ORC writer.

Type like this:

```
foo:uniontype<void,array<string>>
```

Causing:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad primitive category VOID
```

Are nullable columns allowed in ORC?

Answer (score 0):

In ORC and Hive, all columns are nullable. A better translation of the Avro type would be array.

We could add void support to ORC, but it doesn't add any value for any reasonable schema.

Please file a Jira for fixing the Avro translation.